# How to change border color of table and remove padding of table using boot strap css.?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had create table with help of bootstrap css. I want to remove padding of cell and bordercolor black to whole table only with bootstrap css. I don't want to create my own css.Only from boot strap classes I want to remove padding and provide border color black to whole table.
Thanx in advance.
plz help me.....

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the class rule by adding   **!important**    attribute to desired property
like

```
.table{padding:0 !important}
```

Comment: Where should i write this ? 
like
<table class="table table-border" {padding:0 !important}>
</table>??

Comment: I have no access to change css. I have to just use predefined classes of boot strap.

Comment: in that case you can write this in the html itself as inline css

Comment: <table class="table table-border" style="padding:0!important"> </table>

Answer (score 0):

```
 .table-bordered td {
     border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
 }
 .table tfoot > tr > td {
     padding: 8px;
     line-height: 1.428571429;
     vertical-align: top;
     border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
 }
 .table thead > tr > th {
     vertical-align: bottom;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
 }
```